# Php disk_free_space() always reads from boot partition

Tags: php, debian, ntfs, diskspace, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to retrieve the free space on a usb hard disk attached to my server (using php), however disk_free_space() always returns the space available on the boot partition.
Here is a summary of my server setup:

```
Rasbperry Pi 2 running rasbian.
php version: 5.4.39-0+deb7u2
booting from 32 gb sd card with about 24 gb free
3TB ntfs gpt usb hard drive mounted 
ntfs-3g installed on system
```

test code:

```
<?
echo ":".disk_free_space("")."\n";
echo "/".disk_free_space("/")."\n";
echo "/mnt/drive:".disk_free_space("/mnt/drive")."\n";
?>
```

output

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: apc.shm_size now uses M/G suffixes, please update your ini files in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  disk_free_space(): No such file or directory in /home/pi/test.php on line 2
:
/24991305728
/mnt/drive:24991305728
```

Comment: Is it possible that `/mnt/drive/` is another mount point for the root partition (not "boot", as you have it)?

Comment: Is /mnt a mounted network drive? This is from the docs: Note: This function will not work on remote files as the file to be examined must be accessible via the server's filesystem.

Comment: @Mike, /mnt/drive is definitely not the root partition.

Comment: @STLMikey /mnt/drive is a usb connected harddrive, not a network drive.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. When I reformatted the hard-drive, the UUID for it changed, invalidating my config in /etc/fstab.  So the drive was accessible, but not being mounted with ntfs3g, so I guess there were issues reading it's capacity.  When I updated the line in fstab to the new UUID it started working correctly:

```
UUID={newuuid} /mnt/drive ntfs-3g defaults,permissions 0 0
```